# Keyboard Issue, how to reset keyboard in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard

Since couple of months i have an annoying keyboard issue on Ubuntu 20.04.

**Issue:**
Ctrl + T : open Terminal
Click on Firefox icon: open new instance of FF instead of current FF window.
Scroll in FF: do a zoom
Click on FF tab: select other tab
...

With that i understand a key (Ctrl or Alt probably are virtually pressed), my physical keyboard have no issue at least on other OS and happen only time to time on Ubuntu. I think this is a OS issue.
Some time i fix it by doing Win+Alt, but some time no combination can't fix it except restart computer.

Comment: sorry, I don't think you have formulated your problem and question understandably

Comment: Sorry for that, i mean something while i'm working some action do not respond as expected like "Ctrl + T" open terminal instead of "Ctrl + Alt + T".

Answer (score 0):

you can go to `setting >>> keyboard` and try following items:

- special character entry
- keyboard shortcuts

Comment: i did not make any change on the keyboard settings.